# Cannot deserialize instance of 'java.util.date' out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, reactjs, serialization, java.util.date

Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of ``java.util.Date` out of START_OBJECT token

I am trying to set the default date picker to show pacific time in REACT using functional Component. useState()

**REACT**

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
return(<TextField
         id="datetime-local-startTime"
         type="datetime-local"
         defaultValue={startDate}
         className={classes.textField}
         onChange={setDefaultStartDate(startDate)}
       />)
const setDefaultStartDate = (date) => {
        date.setHours(date.getHours() - 8);
        setStartDate(date.toISOString().substr(0, 16))
        return date.toISOString().substr(0, 16);
    }
```

**JAVA**

```
@JsonProperty("startDate")
private Date startDate;

@JsonProperty("endDate")
private Date endDate;`
```

Comment: Please share how you are parsing this and possibly more information. Whatever you've parsing, you have sent a json object but you're looking for a date or something.

Comment: Json object with date field

Comment: React component is materialui component datetime

Comment: Can you send the json that is received by the api?

Comment: It's trying to send json to api...I m getting error msg on start date rather then an object

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that the react date is not a string but a complex object. When you send that object up as part of the request, Jackson is expecting to find a the same class definition on the server side to deserialize into. In other words, `react date class != java date class`. You either need to define a custom jackson Deserializer for this date on the Java side, or convert the react date into a simple string that can be deserialized by Jackson.